# Drupal combine nodes and comments in view

Tags: drupal-7, comments, drupal-views

I have a view with nodes of the type 'Note' (custom CT). I have A view with comments that are associated with those nodes. How can I combine these views into one view so that I can filter them individually on the date ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to make one view with notes and comments both in it and then using contextual filter to get the date.

Alternatively, to get them in a top wth notes and a bottom with comments, use attachment displays to get two views into one. Make your top view, then use 'Add+' where the page and block buttons are (top left) are to select a new 'attachment'. Make new view here then add the two together with 'Attachment Settings' then 'Attach to' and choose your first view. Magic!

Comment: The attachement solution is no good. I want the nodes and the comments to be mingled between each other and ordere chronologically. The first options is impossible ? comments are not node types, and thus can't be used in a node type view